# how to create folders in a C# class library

Tags: c#

I want to build a class library with folders representing a namespace structure. When I import my class library into a project I can only see classes on the root level. No classes within folders are part of the class library anymore. Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you looking at the solution explorer or the class explorer ?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to tell. Are those classes `public`? Do you use the correct namespaces to access them?

Comment: I found the issue. I actually did not provide a public access modifier to the class within the folder. After adding a public access modifier to the class, it was then part of the dll class library. thx for pointing that out Rene Vogt.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer, press the "Show All Files" button.

[image]

Folders not included in the project will now appear, but be greyed out.  Find the folders with the missing classes, right click and choose 'Include In Project'.